# SELECT (DISTINCT COUNT) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have done this without much effort on T-SQL, but I want to implement the same on Excel VBA. How to achieve this? I have a field on my sheet called "Stops" which pertains to the Stops that a truck makes while delivering its order. I want to count the total number of stops. 1 stop can have multiple orders to be delivered. The data on the stops column is something like:

```
Order#  Stops
1527305 1
1527305 1
1529418 2
1529418 2
1527299 3
1527299 3
1528894 5
1528894 5
1529529 6
1529529 6
1529518 7
1529518 7
1527522 8
1527522 8
```

So, the final count should be just 7 unique stops. The current code looks at the last row and takes it as the total stops (which is wrong). The code that I have right now is as follows:

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Select  ' H = stop number
    Selection.Value = curStop 'sets stop number
        If Selection.Value = 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
            curStop = ActiveCell.Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.Value = curStop
        End If
```

I have done something on T-SQL with one line of code, but dont know how to do this on Excel. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok. I found the answer and hence I thought of posting the same here. I can use the Frequency function to count the distinct values for the stops and it gives me the correct result. 
Here is the one liner code (The range can be adjusted)

    =SUM(N(FREQUENCY(H177:H190,H177:H190)>0))

I found the code on the following page:

[http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Duplicates.aspx][1]


  [1]: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Duplicates.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$15,1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$15,$B$2:$B$15)))
```

as an array formula solution, assuming your data is in B2:B15. Array formulae are, of course, entered with a Ctrl + Shift + Enter, rather than an enter, so maybe your solution is slightly better :)

Also shouldn't your question say the answer is **7** stops, and not **5**???

Comment: My bad..I was looking at a different data set!

Comment: Not a problem :)... It actually had me stumped, else I would have posted the answer much earlier!!

Answer (score 1):

You already have a formula-based solution, and that may be what you wish to use in this case.
If you are curious about a way to solve the problem using VBA, read on.

For the problem of identifying unique values a dictionary can be an appropriate data-structure.
In particular, you may check for a key's existence before adding a key.
Tested example follows:

*(Please note: you must enable (check the box) Tools > References > "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".)*

```
Option Explicit

Function uniq_dict(ByRef row As Long, ByRef col As Long)
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For row = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
        If Not dict.Exists(ws.Cells(row, col).Value) Then
            dict.Add ws.Cells(row, col).Value, Null '# can insert something here 
        End If
    Next row

    Set uniq_dict = dict
End Function

Sub call_uniq_dict()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k() As Variant
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = uniq_dict(1, 1)

    Debug.Print "total items in dict:", dict.Count
    k = dict.Keys
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "  dict key:", k(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:

```
total items in dict:         5 
  dict key:    1 
  dict key:    2 
  dict key:    3 
  dict key:    7 
  dict key:    8
```

Comment: Thank you Bernie. Now I am encountering another problem. I want to insert either function (to count the distinct values) on a sheet where there are subtotals for the routes traveled. So in effect the data would look like 
Route1
Order#  Stop#
Route2
Order# Stop
How would I insert the function at every subtotal level? I am thinking of making dynamic ranges based on the blank cells when a subtotal is inserted. Any ideas?
Route1

Comment: @RajivVarma: You're most welcome. It seems that you have moved on to a different problem. Would you please consider posting a new question? Thank you.

Comment: Perfect. New question on the way. Will post the link here very soon.

Comment: here is the link for the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879593/dynamically-determining-range-to-apply-formula-function-in-excel