# Dynamically determining range to apply formula/function in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I need to determine the range to apply the Frequency function. Here's what the problem is. On the given sheet, I have subtotals for my data and there is a column which has "Stop" Values. 
The data would look something like:

```
Route1
Order#                          Stop#   Qty 
001016                           1       5
008912                           1       5
062232                           2       6
062232                           3       2
069930                           4       1
1000                             4       3
1001                             4       4
1001                             5       8
1003                             8       1

Route 1 Subtotal                 6       35 

Route2
Order#                          Stop#   Qty 
10065                             1      5
10076                             1      5  
10077                             2      6
10079                             3      2
10087                             4      1
10098                             4      3
10109                             4      4
10171                             5      8
10175                             8      1
Route 2 Subtotal                  6     35
```

How do I write VBA code for calculating the distinct stop values. I need the distinct count of the stop#. Hence in the example above you can see that the total stops are 6 because 1 stop can have multiple orders and 1 route can have multiple orders/stop. Hope I am making sense here. Let me know how I would write my VBA code for this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Will the data set contain empty cells for entering a subtotal? In the above example, for instance, will the "Route # Subtotal" lines be already present? Also, I presume Route #s are unique, i.e. no two routes share the same name?? I ask because if this is so, the vba code can use this fact to search for the appropriate range

Comment: The data set will not have any empty cells. The data will be grouped together using the subtotal function on the Route# field. For example, after 10 lines of details for Route1, we have the "Total for Route1" and obviously, the column A will be blank for this particular line. The route numbers will be unique every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Stop Subtotal unique count, try this formula (adjust ranges as required):

```
=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(B2:B10,B2:B10))
```

Comment: Thanks for the formula Lori. What I am looking for is how to apply this formula at the subtotal level. The sheet will have many datasets like above and I need to add the the Frequency formula at these subtotal levels only. I am trying to put together a VBA code for doing this as I am not going to run this macro.

Comment: If you're trying to get the address of the range to apply the formula to you might be able to extract this from any existing subtotal formulas or otherwise something like: `range(activecell.End(xlUp),activecell.End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Address` and loop through each cell in the subtotals.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that out real soon and let you know how that goes.